# A waterfall end problem. It prompt back to other dialog instead of ending

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, helper, adaptive-cards

I have in total 4 dialogs. In one of the dialogs (named "product issue") I have to go a new dialog named "resolution", at the end of that dialog their itself at particular condition.  An adaptive card is displayed from product issue have 4 option in it, on "Overload" ,"Computer Rebooting", "Low Backup" it goes to new dialog named "resolution", where it has two steps: in step one display an adaptive card again with 4 options named 
 "Restart Machine", "off device","Press,Need assistance...when I select any option three open from step 1 like "Restart Machine", "off device","Press..it should display the adaptive card and end their itself and need assistance it will go back to product issue and will display defined steps for it. But when I choose
 "Restart Machine", "off device" or press ..dialog is not ending and it it going back to product issue.

Product issue:

```cs
     namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
     {
      public class ProductIssue : ComponentDialog
       {
        private const string UserInfo = "value-userInfo";
        protected readonly ILogger _logger;
        protected readonly string[] _end =
         {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "ValidationCard.json"),
        };
        protected readonly string[] _date =
         {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "Datepicker.json"),
        };
        protected readonly string[] _time =
        {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "Timepicker.json"),
        };
        protected readonly string[] _cards =
         {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "State.json"),
         };
        protected readonly string[] _card =
       {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "City.json"),
         };
        protected readonly string[] _purchase =
       {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "purchase.json"),

         };

        protected readonly string[] _service =
          {
             Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "Service.json")
         };
        public ProductIssue(string dialogId) : base(dialogId)
        {

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
            if (dialogId == $"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain")
                AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
               optionAsync,
               InoptionAsync,
               AnyOthersAsync,
               OtpAsync,
               UserauthenticationAsync,
               CityAsync,
               purchaseAsync,
               purchaseYesAsync,
                reviewAsync,
                lastAsync,
                EndAsync
                }));

            else if (dialogId == $"{ nameof(Resolution)}.resolution")
                AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
                 {
                       OtpAsync,
                       UserauthenticationAsync,
                       CityAsync,
                       purchaseAsync,
                       purchaseYesAsync,
                       reviewAsync,
                       lastAsync,
                        EndAsync
                 }));
            else
                AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
                {
                       InoptionAsync,
                       AnyOthersAsync,
                       OtpAsync,
                       UserauthenticationAsync,
                       CityAsync,
                       purchaseAsync,
                       purchaseAsync,
                       purchaseYesAsync,
                       reviewAsync,
                       lastAsync,
                        EndAsync

                }));

            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain", ValidateAsync));

        }


        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> optionAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment4());
            reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment5());
            reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment6());
            reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment7());
            var promptOptions = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select any option.") };
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InoptionAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
            if (choice == "Inverter" || choice == "Fan" || choice == "Battery")
            {
                var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment8());
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            }
            else 
            {
                var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
                reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.GetHeroCard5().ToAttachment());
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("I will be here if you need me further."), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
            }
            var promptOptions = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("i will") };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> AnyOthersAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
            if (choice == "Any Others")
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("We are here to help you."), cancellationToken);
            }
            else if(choice == "Overload" || choice ==  "Computer Rebooting" || choice == "Low Backup")
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{nameof(Resolution)}.start", null, cancellationToken);
            }

            var anyothers = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your specific problem.") };

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), anyothers, cancellationToken);

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> OtpAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
          stepContext.Values[UserInfo] = new UserInput();
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("To proceed further, we will be verifying your mobile number by sending an OTP."), cancellationToken);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("We have just sent an OTP to your number"), cancellationToken);
            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Kindly enter the OTP sent(6 digit number)"),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Incorrect OTP entered. Kindly re-enter the OTP sent (6 digit number).")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(MainDialog)}.fromMain", num, cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> UserauthenticationAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var Otp = (UserInput)stepContext.Values[UserInfo];
            int value;
            var len = (stepContext.Result.ToString()).Length;
            bool success = int.TryParse(stepContext.Result.ToString(), out value);
            if (success == true && len == 6)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Thanks. Your OTP is confirmed."), cancellationToken);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("We are now validating your number against our database. This may take a minute."), cancellationToken);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("We will be registering you as a user in our system. Please provide a few details."), cancellationToken);
            }

            var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment9());
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hello"), cancellationToken);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Please select the state you are located in"), cancellationToken);

            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_cards[r.Next(_cards.Length)]);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(" Selected state is:")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), num, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CityAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_card[r.Next(_card.Length)]);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(" Selected city is:")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), num, cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> purchaseAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_purchase[r.Next(_purchase.Length)]);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), num, cancellationToken);
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> purchaseYesAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
            if (choice.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_date[r.Next(_date.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            }
            else if (choice.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_service[r.Next(_service.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            }

            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), num, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> reviewAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
            if (choice.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Our representative will be reviewing your comments shortly."), cancellationToken);
                Random r = new Random();
                var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_end[r.Next(_end.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);

            }
            else
            {
                ServiceDate serviceDate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceDate>(choice);
                Random r2 = new Random();
                var validationcards = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_service[r2.Next(_service.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcards), cancellationToken);

            }

            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), num, cancellationToken);

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> lastAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();

            if (choice.ToLower() == "yes")
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_time[r.Next(_time.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            }

            else if (choice.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Our representative will be reviewing your comments shortly."), cancellationToken);
                Random r = new Random();
                var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_end[r.Next(_end.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
               return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
            }
            var num = new PromptOptions
            {
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("")
            };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), num, cancellationToken);


        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> EndAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
            ServiceDate serviceDate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceDate>(choice);

            if (serviceDate.id == "12")
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Starting to raise service request with the team. Please give it a minute."), cancellationToken);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Our representative will be reviewing your comments shortly."), cancellationToken);
            }
            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_end[r.Next(_end.Length)]);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);

        }
        private Task<bool> ValidateAsync(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            int value;
            int len = (promptContext.Context.Activity.Text).Length;
            bool success = int.TryParse(promptContext.Context.Activity.Text, out value);
            if (success == true && len == 6)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }

    }

    public class ServiceDate
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string value { get; set; }

        public string date { get; set; }
    }

}
**resolution dialog**
     namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
    {
     public class Resolution : ComponentDialog
    {
        protected readonly string[] _solution =
        {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "resolution.json"),
        };
        protected readonly string[] _action =
        {
            Path.Combine(".", "Resources", "ValidationCard.json"),
        };

        public Resolution(string dialogId) : base(dialogId)
        {
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(Resolution)}.solution"));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog($"{nameof(Resolution)}.start", new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                solutionAsync,
                actionAsync

                }));
            InitialDialogId = $"{nameof(Resolution)}.start";
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt($"{nameof(Resolution)}.end"));
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> solutionAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            Random r = new Random();
            var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_solution[r.Next(_solution.Length)]);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
            var anyothers = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please select the problem resloution.") };
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync($"{nameof(Resolution)}.solution", anyothers, cancellationToken);

        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> actionAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string choice = stepContext.Result.ToString();
            if (choice == "Restart Machice" || choice == "off device" || choice == "Press")
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                var validationcard = Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment2(_action[r.Next(_action.Length)]);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(validationcard), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync($"{nameof(Resolution)}.end", cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync($"{ nameof(Resolution)}.resolution", null, cancellationToken);
     } } }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to end a dialog and NOT return to ANY previous dialog, you need to use `CancellAllDialogs`. It looks like you are using only `EndDialog`, which only ends the currently active dialog.

Comment: @ShivaniSingh This is correct. To add a little clarification, you're calling `EndDialog` while `Resolution` is the active dialog, so only that dialog is ended. The bot will then resume from `ProductIssue` dialog with the `OtpAsync` step (since `Resolution` dialog was called with a `return` in `AnyOthersAsync` step).

Comment: return  await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken); i add this line in the place of enddialogasyn...its not working..can you plez help me out

Comment: can any can help me..i am struck here

Comment: The change you made should be working. Can you clarify what is happening after the change to `CancelAllDialogsAsync`?